# C# application not running on different machines

Tags: c#

I have a C# application that loads fine on my development machine but fails to even start on Win2008 machine.

Checked Frameworks and they match up, Net 4.0

I immediately suspected the problem was arising from references to specific files that I was reading from and sure enough, using some test code I narrowed it down to a single line.

```
public static string[] salesArray = (File.ReadAllLines("sales.txt").ToArray());
```

If I comment out the above line, the test app starts, if I leave it in, it fails.  Any ideas?

I am copying the Debug directory to the second machine (sales.txt) within it.

This is the entire code.  The app does nothing but open a blank window.

```
namespace testServer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public static string[] salesArray = (File.ReadAllLines("sales.txt").ToArray());

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a relative path, when you've done nothing to set the current directory (or even sanity-check that the current directory is what you think it is), strikes me as an extremely bad idea.

Comment: I did try setting the file to @"c:\sales.txt" and made sure the file was in there.  On one machine it works and another it doesn't.

Comment: I found the issue, even though I had NET 4.0 on both machines, the development machine also had legacy NET versions on it.  I guess NET 4.0 isn't backwards compatible because as soon as I installed NET 3.5 on the second machine the app runs fine.

Answer (score 3):

Two potential issues jump out:

1) The current working directory of the app isn't what you think it is:
If you can print/show this, you would know for sure.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx

Because you are specifying a relative path, the current working directory is what the file is being resolved against.

2) Perhaps permissions.  You might right-click, 'Run as administrator' as a quick check into that theory.

Comment: I tried changing to: public static string[] salesArray = (File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\sales.txt").ToArray());    Also, tried running as admin, problem persists.  I added string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            MessageBox.Show(path); to program.cs which runs first and do see a message box with the current directory but as soon as I hit OK it crashes when it hits the ReadLine code.

Comment: Like Steve said, you should wrap that line with a try/catch, and MessageBox.Show(e) that.

Comment: I used try catch, here is what comes up:  "The type initializer for 'testserver.Form1.cs' threw and exception."

Comment: Take that line of out of the static block, if it's still there.  Let your form show.  I believe that error is because the type isn't constructing.  There might be an inner exception more useful.  Or, just use a debugger and inspect the exception more fully.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a better mechanism to find that file, and check for its existence (ie: `File.Exists`) prior to opening it.

This will also let you report to the user if there is a problem, such as the file not existing where you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Put an exception handler around the code.  You can get the error message and can handle the failure gracefully.

It should handle all errors (file not found, file in use, permission errors, etc.).